# MongoDB View memory usage

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongodb, I have been wondering if the view is loaded in ram on demand or it is only referenced ? the only thing mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/views/) is the disk persistence .

> A MongoDB view is a queryable object whose contents are defined by an aggregation pipeline on other collections or views. MongoDB does not persist the view contents to disk. A view's content is computed on-demand when a client queries the view. MongoDB can require clients to have permission to query the view. MongoDB does not support write operations against views.

I need to know this information because i'm working on a Big Data project and if this is true it will be a serious problem.